# Set the UITableView frame according to number of cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am fetching a list of data from web service. I want my table to show only the number of rows which contains data not the rest(empty rows). Below mentioned method i used to do so, but it is not effective, it only colors the non empty cells. Can anyone guide me for this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set clearColor and check.

Comment: How you set the separatorColor property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
if(arrayServ.count > 6)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 6 * 45);
}
else
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, arrayServ.count * 45);
}
```

instead of handling each case separatly?

Also if one reads your question he could think you might want to hide the empty cells and not that you want to adjust the framesize of the uitableview.

Comment: It is one and same thing to show only filled cells or hide empty cells.

Comment: Well. I had one case, where i had empty cells between my filled cells and just wanted to hide those empty cells.
That requires an other approach than your problem, but thats another story.
I forgot the limitation to 6 rows in my answer btw. Just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger*)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]init];
    return view;
}
```

This will not change frame but hide line between empty cell.
I think you want that.

Comment: This is just giving the footer frame, how to fit it's frame to table view boundary.

Comment: I have already told you that "This will not change frame but hide line between empty cell" you have use CGRectMake to change frame of UITableView

Answer (score 0):

try using this

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

```
    return array.count;

}
```

where array will be your list data array which you getting from web service

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this will show only data in rows, not hide the empty cells

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
//return 172;
if([arrayServ count] == 1)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 40);
}

if([arrayServ count] == 2)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 85);
}

if([arrayServ count] == 3)
{
   // return 172;
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 130);
}

if([arrayServ count] == 4)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 175);
}

if([arrayServ count] == 5)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 220);
}

if([arrayServ count] == 6)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 265);
}

if([arrayServ count] == 7)
{
    tableService.frame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 310, 310);
}

if([arrayServ count] > 7)
{
    tableService.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
}
return 0;
}
```